# sending component content as an email using JSTL

Tags: jstl, aem, aem-6

in AEM6 SP3, I am trying to read the content from a page using a taglib in one component and send it as an email, The JSP piece code in the component is as follows:

```
 <c:set var="morContent" value="${is:MORContent(resourceResolver)}"/>
  \${morContent}
```

except I am not able to get the content in the email,I just see ${morContent} displayed literally instead of actual content,  the but the same thing works fine when I try to display in a web page.

what am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: can jstl work with jsp in an email ?

Comment: Shouldn't you be emailing the html output of your jsp rather than the jsp itself?